# What's the correct notation for a minimum of a row of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

- $I=\{1,\cdots,m\}$ denote the indices of the rows of a matrix $A$
- Let $J=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ denote the indices of the columns of matrix $A$
- Let $x_{i,j}$ denote the value of the element $A[i,j]$

I need to use a notation to indicate the minimum value for each row. Is it correct if I do it like so?
$$\min_{j\in J}(x_{i,j}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall i\in I$$

Comment: Instead of $x_{i,j}$ why not $a_{i,j}$ since your matrix is named $A$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If I needed a vector of row-minima, I'd write
$$
u_i = \min_{j\in J} x_{ij}, ~i = 1, \ldots, m.
$$

In other words, almost exactly what you've written. In general, I like to denote the $ij$ element of a matrix $A$ by $a_{ij}$, so my real preferred answer would be 
$$
u_i = \min_{j\in J} a_{ij}, ~i = 1, \ldots, m.
$$

Comment: Thanks you, I agree with you