# Notation to find the indices of the columns that contain the minimums of each row in a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I am doing something that is easy in Python, but I need to document what I'm doing in a paper in a professional way.

I have an $n x m$ matrix, $D$. In code, I pull out the column indices that contain the minimum value in each row. For example, let D be a 4x3 matrix...

```
[1 9 9
 9 1 9  
 9 9 1  
 1 9 9]
```

Looking for some notation that defines the computation that produces a 1x4 vector $x$, such that $x=[1,2,3,1]$.

I've [seen this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871673/whats-the-correct-notation-for-a-minimum-of-a-row-of-a-matrix), and it helped, but it just gets me the actual minimum values in the rows, so it will produce something like [1,1,1,1]. But I need the column indices that correspond to the values, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Not finding an answer, I made a workaround by making up my own function and breaking the problem into two stages.

A function that selects one column for each row, as specified by $\vec{x}$, and then sums all the selections:
$\textbf{SelectAndSumColumns}(\vec{x}, D):s$
Let $x=[x_1​,x_2​,...,x_n​]$, a vector of $n$ assignments, such that $x_i​=j$ means row $i$ selects column $j$.
Return the sum of the selected columns: $s=\sum_{i} ​Dij​∣Dj​=x_i$​.

Then, the thing I originally wanted, $\vec{x}$, is simply...
$\vec{x} = \operatorname*{argmin}_{\vec{x}}\textbf{SelectAndSumColumns}(\vec{x}, D)$

This is no longer math, but just me waving my hand in a mathy way.
Is this ridiculous? Perhaps.
Is there a way to do it with real math?...you tell me :)